# UIView observer in .cpp file

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, addobserver

How to add an observer to UIView frame in .cpp file

like this (objective-c):

`[view  addObserver:videoAd forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];`

Comment: Are you asking if there is a C++ API for interfacing with an Objective-C class?

Comment: I am just looking for a way to get the call back function called @SteveWilford


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context